# Setting Canvas Limits Over the Existing Dataset Values

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I've got a little problem with html5 canvas. I've got a couple of line charts made but they have a problem with maximum grid values (sort of field limits inside the canvas itself). The chart is building from a dataset coming from the database and only through these values.

The example: sample chart

[image: sample chart]

As you can see here, the above limit is 5.55, and the question is how to change that to a bigger value (for example, using a percentage of such maximum value or something so that other charts' offsets would match as well)?

The code:

```
$('#graf_' + i + '').html('<canvas id="lineChart' + i + '" width="' + $(".graf").width() + '" height="200"></canvas>');

var lineData = {
    labels: data["headers"],
    datasets: [{
        label: data["rates"][i]["VltName"],
        fillColor: "transparent",
        strokeColor: data["rates"][i]["VltColor"],
        pointColor: data["rates"][i]["VltColor"],
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: getRatesArr
    }]
};
var lineOptions = {
    scaleShowGridLines: true,
    scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
    scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
    bezierCurve: false,
    pointDot: true,
    pointDotRadius: 4,
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
    pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
    datasetStroke: true,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
    datasetFill: true
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart" + i).getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, lineOptions);
```

Hope my explanation is not too vague. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you update to the latest Chart.js version (currently [v2.6.0](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.6.0)), you can use the `max` tick configuration option to set the max number to display on the axis:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                max: yourMaxNum
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

If you want to set `yourMaxNum` to the largest number in all your dataset arrays, simply use the JavaScript [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) method to determine this number, and set the above chart config option to this number when you create all your line charts.

The [Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options) lists additional tick configuration options that you might also find useful.